# How to find the long running queries

Tags: performance, monitoring, marklogic, long-running-processes

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

We would like to see the long running queries on MarkLogic App Server.

We were looking at documentation and [this](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/63/0/gathering-information-to-troubleshoot-long-running-queries) link

This knowledgeable talks about running "appserver-status.xqy" in qconsole to generate report on queries running currently.

What we need to know is list of long running queries in the last month and then investigate on how we can improve it.

Is there any way we can extract these information?

Comment: The data from that script is not persisted, so you would need a mechanism to schedule it to run periodically, and to persist the data.  You could alter that script, or you could upgrade to a more recent release and use [Request Monitoring](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/performance/request_monitoring) which will log requests.

Comment: Hello MG, Thanks for your reply, So upgrading to 9.0.12 will start logging App request monitoring ?

Comment: Not automatically, but the feature is available if you perform the steps in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks MG for your reply, Can you please post as a answer, i will then Mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from that script is not persisted, so there would need to be a mechanism to schedule it to run periodically, and persist the data.  You could alter the script, or you upgrade to a more recent release and use [Request Monitoring](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/performance/request_monitoring).

The process to enable Request Monitoring is in the documentation, and once it's enabled, the requests will be logged in the app server RequestMonitoring log.